# After formatting USB drive, "Failed to take ownership"

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, ext4, disk-formatting

I've used the GUI Disks to format a USB drive just purchased as ext4. After formatting, I get the message:

`Failed to take ownership of newly created filesystem: Cannot mount /dev/sda1 at /run/udisks2/temp-mount-BXBBW1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (udisks-error-quark, 0)`.

I've also tried using gparted to format it. There, I see:

```
dumpe2fs: Corrupt extent header while reading journal super block</i>

<I>Unable to reads the contents of this file system!
```

I've tried replacing the partition table, and I've also tried formatting to FAT32 to no success.

Strangely, formatting as FAT works fine and I can use the drive, but I'd prefer not to use FAT if I can avoid it.

Comment: Probably defective or about to become so.

Comment: I solved the similar problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1478086/849328